# Kubernetes secret is really secret?

Tags: kubernetes

While I developed an API server, I needed to give some account information to API server, which should not be shown to anyone.
K8s recommends secret for this kind of situation, so I used.

But I wonder if the secret is really secret.
Secret is just base 64 "encoded" text, not "encrypted".

When I see an arbitary secret like below,

```
namespace: ZGVmYXVsdA==
```

I can easily know the real value of it by decoding.

```
namespace: default
```

In such a this situation, is secret really helpful for security?
What I know about the security advantage of secret is that it is on-memory not on-node file system.
But I think that is not enough for security.

Thank you.

Comment: you are right in this case but you can get the base 64 when you have access to the secret and decode and check the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Kubernetes Secrets documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#risks):

**Risks**

- In the API server, secret data is stored in etcd(**by default, etcd data is not encrypted**); therefore:

  1. **Administrators should enable encryption at rest for cluster data** (requires v1.13 or later).
  2. **Administrators should limit access to etcd to admin users.**
  3. Administrators may want to wipe/shred disks used by etcd when no longer in use.
  4. **If running etcd in a cluster, administrators should make sure to use SSL/TLS for etcd peer-to-peer communication.**
- If you configure the secret through a manifest (JSON or YAML) file which has the secret data encoded as base64, sharing this file or checking it in to a source repository means the secret is compromised. **Base64 encoding is not an encryption method and is considered the same as plain text.**
- Applications still need to protect the value of secret after reading it from the volume, such as not accidentally logging it or transmitting it to an untrusted party.
- **A user who can create a Pod that uses a secret can also see the value of that secret. Even if the API server policy does not allow that user to read the Secret, the user could run a Pod which exposes the secret.**
- **Currently, anyone with root permission on any node can read any secret from the API server**, by impersonating the kubelet. It is a planned feature to only send secrets to nodes that actually require them, to restrict the impact of a root exploit on a single node.

Also check great post [Can Kubernetes Keep a Secret? It all depends what tool you’re using](https://itnext.io/can-kubernetes-keep-a-secret-it-all-depends-what-tool-youre-using-498e5dee9c25), especcially "**What’s wrong with Kubernetes plain Secrets?**" part..

I hope that answered your question, but generally @Harsh Manvar  is right: you should have an access first to that secret.

Answer (score 1):

You should limit access using authorization policies such as RBAC.

You'll need to create a `Role/ClusterRole` with appropriate permissions and then bind (using `RoleBinding/ClusterRoleBinding`) that to a user and/or a service account (can be used in pod definition then), depending on your use case.

You can look at the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole) to create Role & ClusterRole and the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding) for RoleBinding and ClusterRoleBinding.

Comment: I also wondered how to use the secret safely, and you answered that question. Thank you.